# Found what appears to be effectively a bogus tag - what to do?

Tags: support, tags

This [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/371361/identification-of-a-part-on-a-power-lines-lightning-arrester) has the tag **lightn** 
which has no other references.

It's easy to delete the tag at the question itself, but how does one get the tag removed from the [forum's list of available tags](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags)?

Comment: Looks fine to me, It has been fixed.

Comment: Yes, I see it's been fixed. But is there a right way to get the tag removed from the list of tags, or just come here and make note of it?

Comment: Talk to someone with over 20k rep, or a diamond mod or earn 20k rep https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges This can be done on the meta, or in the mod chat room, or with flagging appropriately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the errant tag has been removed from the question (i.e. the question has been correctly re-tagged) then the (now unused) tag *should* be auto-purged from the list of tags - assuming that it is not in use elsewhere. This happens after a certain period of time. when the auto-purge scripts are run, which I believe happens daily at *03:00 UTC*.

See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags#answer-19754) to [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or “zombie”) tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags), the emphasis is mine:

> You should edit out the tag from all the questions that use it. Note
>   that you should probably seek consensus on the per-site meta before
>   doing so, if the tag was somehow added to a significant number of
>   questions without anyone noticing the misspelling.
>
> **Tags not associated with any question are automatically destroyed at
>   03:00 UTC every day.**
>
> Tags which are misspelled should have the questions under them
>   retagged to the appropriate tag, which will result in the misspelled
>   tag's destruction due to having no uses.